# How to fix error "WARNING: test command found but not installed in testenv" for tox?

Tags: makefile, python-sphinx, tox

Using tox 3.7.0-2 I get an error

```
WARNING: test command found but not installed in testenv
  cmd: /usr/bin/make
  env: /builds/common/doc/docs-create/.tox/docs
Maybe you forgot to specify a dependency? See also the whitelist_externals envconfig setting.
```

But in the `tox.ini` file I have the following declaration:

```
[testenv:docs]
deps =
    setuptools
    gitpython
    click
commands =
    make clean
    make html SPHINXOPTS="-v"
allowlist_externals = 
    make
```

which seems to "allow" the external `make`. So what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a super outdated version of `tox`.

With this old version you need to use...

```
whitelist_externals = make
```

in your configuration file.

The solution is also suggested in the error message.

For more information see https://tox.wiki/en/latest/changelog.html?highlight=whitelist#deprecations-removal-in-next-major-release

Comment: I just do `apt install tox`. How to install a newer version of tox instead?

Comment: Alex, I would appreciate if you accept/upvote my answer. I assume you are using Debian 10 - using packages via apt means you are probably using older packages, but they are maintained and the maintainers make sure you will have no conflict. I would advise you to continue to use those packages - except you miss an important feature. Then you could use https://pypi.org/project/pipx/ to install and run Python CLI apps.

Comment: A `pip install tox` seem to solve my problems.

Comment: Take care to do that `pip install tox` in a virtual environment:
https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/

Comment: No venv needed, as it is installed in a gitlab environment for a gitlab job.